# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error occuring while AWS ACM certificate loaded on HTTPS load balancer for a domain created in GoDaddy

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-acm

1. I have a node js app deployed onto EC2 instance running on port 300 and it is exposed to internet via port 80 & 443 via http load balancers.
2. My security group allows inbound rules on 80 & 443. I have created SSL certificates with ACM for a domain created on GoDaddy (domain name:- [www.abcd-example.com](http://www.abcd-example.com)).
3. For CNAME I added these values,  Host(Name): _57xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5d, Points to(value): _68xxxxxxxxxxx67.bxxxxxxxxxxxj.acm-validations.aws.
4. My ACM certificate was issued and I had loaded these certificate on to load balancer. Now when I try to access the load balancer with https://, I am getting this error : `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.`

I am not sure why this is happening as I had followed all the steps mentioned in AWS docs to dot. Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: What names are actually on the certificate?

Comment: I have loaded 3 certificates from ACM onto ELB. the names of the certificates are www.abcd-example.com, abcd-example.com, *.abcd-example.com

Comment: Those names don't appear to exist. How did you get a certificate for a nonexistent domain?